# How to remove all subscript from Indesign document?

Tags: adobe-indesign, script

I have document its have more than 300 pages. I need to change font type with different colour. Using eyedropper tool i do that but I need to remove subscript from my document because when i use eyedropper for change font type subscript will change to normal text. so i need to remove all subscript from my document. Its there any way kindly please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Open the **Find/Change** window
- Click the **Specify Attributes to Find** icon and at the **Basic Character Format** click **Position** and check **Superscript** → Ok
- Click the **Specify Attributes to Change** icon and at the **Basic Character Format** click **Position** and check **Normal** → Ok
- Click the **Change All** button

[image]